# Event call callback which calls callback

Tags: javascript, module, callback, dom-events

I'm implementing the module pattern and I want to expose an event function.
Here's the code:

```
var module = (function(){
    var self = {},
        cb = $(":checkbox");

    cb.on("change",/* self.OnChange */ ); // ???

    return self;
}());

module.OnChange(callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction(event){
    //do staff
}
```

So, any ideas on how I can access the `OnChange` 'callbackFunction' ?
Or a better way to do this with the module pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often use this pattern within my modules / plugins / libraries:

```
var borrow = function( obj, funcName, funcArg ){
  return function(){
    /// convert arguments to array
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
    /// add in our fixed arg 'change'
    args.unshift( funcArg );
    /// execute the function
    return obj[funcName].apply( obj, args );
  }
}

self.change = borrow( cb, 'on', 'change' );
```

Which should mean outside of your constructor you can call:

```
module.change( callbackFunction );
```

This basically has the effect of directly borrowing the jQuery function, but wrappering it with specific element(s) of your choosing. The above will pass your event listener straight to the checkbox, as if you'd typed the following directly:

```
cb.on( 'change', callbackFunction );
```

You can improve the above to accept more than one fixed argument, like so:

```
var borrow = function( obj, funcName ){
  /// convert arguments to array
  var args1 = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
  /// remove the first two args (obj & funcName) 
  /// which means we now have an array of left over arguments
  /// we'll treat these as 'fixed' and always passed to the 
  /// 'borrowed' function.
  args1.shift(); args1.shift();
  /// return a closure containing our 'borrowed' function
  return function(){
    /// convert arguments to array
    var args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
    /// create a new array combined from the fixed args and the variable ones
    var args = args1.concat( args2 );
    /// execute the function
    return obj[funcName].apply( obj, args );
  }
}
```

A further improvement *(getting rid of the shifts)* would be like so:

```
var borrow = function( obj, funcName ){
  /// convert arguments to array and remove first two arguments
  var args1 = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 );
  /// return a closure containing our 'borrowed' function
  return function(){
    /// convert arguments to array
    var args2 = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );
    /// create a new array combined from the fixed args and the variable ones
    var args = args1.concat( args2 );
    /// execute the function
    return obj[funcName].apply( obj, args );
  }
}
```

Comment: @Daniel Cool :) no problem... it's rather annoying that the `arguments` object doesn't support normal array methods until you've converted it - otherwise the code would be rather neat. Oh btw I've added a better version that gets rid of the need for the array shift().

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making some confusion

```
var module = (function(){
    // here this points to the window object
    var self = this,
        cb = $(":checkbox");

    cb.on("change",/* self.OnChange */ ); // ???
    // here you are returning the window object
    return self;
}());
//since the function was instantaneous, here you are calling onChange() on the window object
module.OnChange(callbackFunction);

function callbackFunction(event){
    //do staff
}
```

What exactly are you trying to do?